# Mudar a parte final do domínio dos e-mails para um varchar randômico

Tags: sql, sql-server

Olá!

Estou procurando uma maneira de mascarar e-mails no banco de dados, mas de uma forma que eu possa reverter eles sem muita dificuldade, caso precise do e-mail real.

Minha ideia é criar uma trigger `AFTER INSERT` para isto. Não será usada em ambiente de produção.

Minha ideia era fazer com que e-mails como:

```
fulano@gmail.com
beltrano@gmail.com
cicrano@yahoo.com.br
```

Virassem:

```
fulano@gmail.gsa
beltrano@gmail.2fs
cicrano@yahoo.com.gg
```

Ou seja, gostaria de alterar os caracteres após o último ponto (.) do e-mail para um varchar randômico. O tamanho do texto substituído não precisa ser o mesmo do texto original.

Alguém conhece uma maneira tranquila de fazer isto? Não sei como pegar a posição do último ponto, isto parece ser crucial para fazer o que quero. Não gostaria de criar uma `function` para isto.

Eu até consigo bagunçar o e-mail antes do `@` com:

```
 UPDATE pessoa 
 SET email=STUFF(email, 1, CHARINDEX('@', email)-1, LEFT(REPLACE(CAST(NEWID() AS VARCHAR(36)), '-', ''), 4+ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()))%4))
```

Resultando em:

```
90FA2E@gmail.com
```

Mas não é o que quero no momento.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode fazer assim:

```
UPDATE pessoa 
 SET email = CONCAT(substring(email, 1, (LEN(email) - CHARINDEX('.',REVERSE(email))) + 1), LEFT(REPLACE(CAST(NEWID() AS VARCHAR(36)), '-', ''), 4+ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()))%4))
```

Primeiro está pegando a posição do ultimo ponto, como não tem uma função nativa para isso(ao menos não conheço e não encontrei nada) é utilizado o `REVERSE` para inverter a *string* e o `CHARINDEX` para na primeira ocorrência. Após isso ele pega a o valor do campo até aquela posição + 1 e adiciona os caracteres aleatorios.

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente! Acabei conseguindo de outro jeito aqui também, também vou postar como resposta.

Comment: Acho que pensamos parecido ;P. Aaah seu jeito ficou mais limpo e com menos função ;)

Comment: minha solução tem 3 reverse, não ficou tão boa assim rs.

Answer (score 3):

Consegui também, de outra maneira:

```
update Pessoa
SET email=REVERSE(STUFF(REVERSE(email), 1, CHARINDEX('.', reverse(email)) - 1, RIGHT(REPLACE(CAST(NEWID() AS VARCHAR(36)), '-', ''), 3)))
```